# copy resulted SQL query table in another table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working in the toad. Here I want to create a procedure in which a new table would be created according to the select query executed. But I am getting this error:

> [Error] PLS-00103 (15: 21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ```
>   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
>    continue
> ```

Below is my procedure code so far can someone guide me where is the mistake.

```
create or replace procedure fire
is
  v_full_name VARCHAR2(500);
  sal varchar(200);
  jobid varchar(100);
  cpct varchar(50);
  mgid varchar(25);
  did varchar(20);
  cid varchar(20);
  rid varchar(20);
  lid varchar(20);

  Begin

  execute immediate create table resquery as

  (
 select HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS 
 Full_Name,HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY as sal,HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID as ji,
 HR.EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT as cmpct,HR.EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID as 
 mgid,HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as dep,HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID as 
 country,HR.DW_REGION.R_ID as region,
 HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID as loc
 into v_full_name,sal,jobid,cpct,mgid,did,cid,rid,lid
 from HR.EMPLOYEES
 join HR.DEPARTMENTS ON 
 HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
 join HR.LOCATIONS    ON HR.DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID=HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
 join HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL ON HR.LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID=HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID
 join HR.DW_REGION    ON HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.REGION_ID=HR.DW_REGION.R_ID
 where HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID='US'
 AND trunc(HR.EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('16/08/2002','DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
 TO_DATE('07/12/2007','DD/MM/YYYY'))




  end
  /
```

Comment: What is the `into` clause meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

Execute immediate is expecting a string. Wrap your CREATE statement in quotes.
Also, execute immediate is a command and must be followed by a semicolon.

```
create or replace procedure fire
is
  v_full_name VARCHAR2(500);
  sal varchar(200);
  jobid varchar(100);
  cpct varchar(50);
  mgid varchar(25);
  did varchar(20);
  cid varchar(20);
  rid varchar(20);
  lid varchar(20);

  Begin

  execute immediate 'create table resquery as
  (
 select HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||'' ''||HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS 
 Full_Name,HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY as sal,HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID as ji,
 HR.EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT as cmpct,HR.EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID as 
 mgid,HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as dep,HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID as 
 country,HR.DW_REGION.R_ID as region,
 HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID as loc
 into v_full_name,sal,jobid,cpct,mgid,did,cid,rid,lid
 from HR.EMPLOYEES
 join HR.DEPARTMENTS ON 
 HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
 join HR.LOCATIONS    ON HR.DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID=HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
 join HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL ON     HR.LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID=HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID
 join HR.DW_REGION    ON HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.REGION_ID=HR.DW_REGION.R_ID
 where HR.COUNTRIES_EXTERNAL.COUNTRY_ID=''US''
 AND trunc(HR.EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE) BETWEEN     TO_DATE(''16/08/2002'',''DD/MM/YYYY'') AND 
 TO_DATE(''07/12/2007'',''DD/MM/YYYY''))';

  end;
  /
```

Comment: ...and escape (=double) any single-quotes that occur in the query

Comment: @Daniel it is giving this error when I execute the procedure

Comment: ORA-06564: object OUTER does not exist
ORA-06512: at "HR.FIRE2", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1

ORA-06564: object OUTER does not exist
ORA-06512: at "HR.FIRE2", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1